# how to get value from request attribute outside loop

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, servlets

I am trying to set values in request object inside for loop and it has been set successfully but How can I get the value if value is set inside the loop. Code which I have tried is given below-

```
        String str = "";                
            for(int i=0; i<sizearray.length; i++){
                str += sizearray[i];                         
                request.setAttribute("ssize", str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("-") + 1));       // two value set ie. 11 and 19
            }               
        out.println(request.getAttribute("ssize"));  // giving one value ie. 19
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are overriding older values with newer values as you are using the same key for all. A better approach would be to create a `Map`, put data into it and then store this map into request object as an attribute.

```
    Map<String, String> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
    String str = "";                
    for(int i=0; i<sizearray.length; i++) {
        str += sizearray[i];                         
        dataMap.put("data"+i, str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("-") + 1));       
    }    
    request.setAttribute("ssize", dataMap);
    out.println(request.getAttribute("ssize")); // this will now give you all values.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help..it worked but i want to put the value of map in request.setattribute

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access the value of request outside the for loop without any problem.

I think the real issue is that you're pretty much overriding the initial value (11) when the last value (19) is set.

This is because you're using the same key for both of the values.

Answer (score 0):

You have get the current value of attribute and concat the new... Try something like:

```
String str = "";                
            for(int i=0; i<sizearray.length; i++){
                str += sizearray[i];                         
                request.setAttribute("ssize", request.getAttribute("ssize") + str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("-") + 1));
            }               
        out.println(request.getAttribute("ssize"));
```